# C++ Program fails if directly fed input in one go

Tags: c++, c, input

Sorry if the title is imperfect, not sure how to word this.

I am doing a program for class, that passed all of my tests, but failed some of the test cases. A bit of research revealed that the way things are input matters.

If I input things like this:
0
0
first
0
second
0
third
0
fourth
0
fifth
1
sixth
1
seventh
1
eigth
(Enter)
1 
ninth
4
(Enter)

Or press enter between each line, all is fine. However, if I copy/paste the entire set of input (or feed it in with cin>> as is done for our grading) I get weirdness that varies between random output (4 triggers output) or segfault 11.

here is the main method (Cant change this)

```
    #include"tDeque.h"
    using namespace std;

    template <typename T>

    void test (T s) {
    Deque<T> *DQ = new Deque<T>();
    T input;
    int op=0;

    while (op<7)
    {

        std::cin>> op;
        switch(op) {
            case 0:
                std::cin>>input;
                try {
                    DQ->push_front(input);
                } catch (exception e) {
                    cout<<"Out of Memory Exception!"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                std::cin>>input;
                try{
                    DQ->push_back(input);
                } catch (exception e) {
                    cout<<"Out of Memory Exception!"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                try{
                    std::cout<<DQ->pop_front()<<std::endl;
                } catch (exception e) {
                    cout<<"Caught Exception for empty stack!"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                try{
                    std::cout<<DQ->pop_back()<<std::endl;
                } catch (exception e) {
                    cout<<"Caught Exception for empty stack!"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout<<DQ->toStr();
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout<<DQ->size()<<std::endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                std::cout<<DQ->empty()<<std::endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int op=0;
    std::string input;
    int type;
    cin>>type;
    string s = "tDeque";
    switch(type) {
        case 0:
            test(s);
            break;
        case 1:
            test(3.2);
            break;
        case 2:
            test(1);
            break;
        default:
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

and here is some of my code (I have been experimenting with putting a break in the code. It helps, but does not solve my problem)

```
void Deque<T>::needIGrow()
{
    try {


        if(front==arrSize-1 &&back==0)
        {   //we need a new array double in size
            T *arr2=new T[arrSize*2];
            //we watn to be 1/3 of the way up the new array to start, and the new array is double in size.
            int newBack=arrSize*2/3;
            int oldFront=front;
            for(int i=back;i<=oldFront;i++)
            { //Transfer old contents to new array
                arr2[i+newBack]=arr[i];
                front=newBack+i;
            }
            // cout << arr2[newBack];
            back=newBack;
            //saftey check. Rounded numbers can be a pain

            //  delete [] arr;
            //update arraysize
            arrSize=arrSize*2;
            //transfer over the array
            arr=arr2;
            // delete [] arr2;
        }
    }
    catch (bad_alloc ex) {
        delete[] _emergencyMemory;

        cerr << "Out of memmory while growing array";
        exit(1);
    }


}

template <typename T>
void Deque<T>::needIShiftLeft()
{
    try
    {
        //if the left has room but the right doesnt, shift left. Do so far enough to move all the way to the middle to minimize this opperation.
        if(front>=arrSize-2)
        {
            int shiftLeftBy=back/2;
            for(int i=0;i+shiftLeftBy<arrSize;i++)
            {
                arr[i]=arr[i+shiftLeftBy];
            }


            back=back-shiftLeftBy;
            front=front-shiftLeftBy;
        }
    }
    catch (bad_alloc ex) {
        delete[] _emergencyMemory;

        cerr << "Out of memmory while shifting array left";
        exit(1);
    }
}

template <typename T>
// Inserts the element at the front of the queue.
void Deque<T>::push_back(T item) {
    sleepToFix();
    try{
        //ignore emtpy Ts. they will cause havok
        //check if we need to grow. the false lets the method we are coming from a back push, so it knows what to check.
        needIGrow();
        //do we need to shift?
        needIShiftLeft();
        if(mySize==0)
        {
            arr[front]=item;
        }
        else{
            front=front+1;
            arr[front]=item;
        }
        mySize++;
    }
    catch (bad_alloc ex) {
        delete[] _emergencyMemory;

        cerr << "Out of memmory while pushing back";
        exit(1);
    }
}




// Removes and returns the element at the back of the queue.
template <typename T>
T Deque<T>::pop_front() {
        sleepToFix();
    if (mySize==0) {
        throw range_error("Tried to pop front on empty stack");
    }
    try{
        //same as pop back
        T s=arr[back];
        //arr[back]=NULL;
        //handle the initial case of front=back, dont seperate them yet
        if(front!=back)
        {
            back=back+1;
        }
        needIShrink();
        if(mySize!=0)
            mySize=mySize-1;
        return s;}
    catch (bad_alloc ex) {
        delete[] _emergencyMemory;

        cerr << "Out of memmory while popping front";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is a *lot* of code. Try to pare it down to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); you might well spot the bug that way, and if you don't you'll still have a much simpler problem to show us.

Answer (score 2):

You can't input more than one word using `cin >> var;`

You'll have to use `std::getline( std::cin , var )` instead and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately the cin portion in the main file is not something I can change. The same main file worked for some of the classmates though.